# aptana studio 3 app explorer folder/file name font size

Tags: aptana

I'm using Apatana studio 3, the folder and file names displayed in app explorer get truncated since the font size is too large, but I can't find a way to change it. Does anyone know how I can modify the font?
(changing themes doesn't help).
Thanks,

David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previously if "invasive theming" was turned on it would apply a version of the editor font to the views. We've found that be a bit ugly and not what most people prefer, so we've broken out a separate theme preference setting for this now. (see http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2334 ). You have to explicitly check a checkbox in *Preferences > Studio > Themes* to apply the editor font to views. If that is on, then you change the font from the same preference page and it applies both the editors and the views. Otherwise it uses the standard Eclipse view font, which is controlled from Preferences > *General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts*.

Comment: Shouldn't those options be there under the same heading? Just curious as to what were the reasons for separating out the two?